# Count number of groups with single rows in r data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table with grouping. I want to count the number groups where only single row is present.

```
dt[ , count := .N, by = .(name, type)]
```

This give me count of rows in each group, By I need the total count of groups which are having single row in it.

Comment: Any feedback would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to count only the groups which has `count` as 1 you can do

```
library(data.table)
nrow(dt[ , .(count := .N), by = .(name, type)][count == 1])
```

Or :

```
sum(dt[ , .(count := .N), by = .(name, type)]$count == 1)
```

---

If you want to subset the rows where number of rows is 1 in a group you can do

```
dt[, .SD[.N == 1], (name, type)]
```

and using `nrow` on this would give you again count of groups.

Answer (score 1):

What about

`table(dt[ , .(count = .N), by = .(name, type)][, count])` ?

@ronakshah 's new answer only works in this setup where 1 line = 1 group because it recycles the `count` for all lines so that you count the number of lines which are in a one-element group which is different that the number of groups with one line.

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
    count(name, type) %>%
    summarise(n = sum(n ==1))
```

---

Or an option with `data.table`

```
dt[, sum(table(paste(name, type)) == 1)]
```